# Read from serialize to populate form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webforms

I did `serialize()` on my form and saved the string, is there any function which can populate values back to the form from serialized string?

Comment: Just to be clear: you are referring to jQuery's [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), not some server-side function (such as PHP's [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php))?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize:571

I recommend instead of serializing data for communication with javascript, you use `JSON`.  PHP should have `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` to help with this, and javascript also has built in `JSON` handling functions, which you may not even need.  For example, if `$.getJSON` gets a valid JSON string from the server, it will be transformed into a javascript object automatically.

EDIT: assuming you are talking about jQuery's `$.serialize()`, that I know of there's no function to undo this (I'm not even sure why that would ever be necessary..)  but this should work:

```
$.each(serialized.split('&'), function (index, elem) {
   var vals = elem.split('=');
   $("[name='" + vals[0] + "']").val(vals[1]);
});
```

Comment: He/she said nothing about server-side. It may be just client-side only (OP just serialized the form and then wants to use it).

Comment: have a slight trouble; it is replacing '@' sign with '%40'

Comment: You have to replace those manually: `.val(decodeURIComponent(vals[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));`

Answer (score 11):

Here is the updated version of Explosion Pills' answer with the additional suggestions in the comments applied:

```
$.each(serialized.split('&'), function (index, elem) {
   var vals = elem.split('=');
   $("[name='" + vals[0] + "']").val(decodeURIComponent(vals[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ')));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous answers, if you have checkbox or radio buttons:

```
$.each(serialized.split('&'), function (index, elem) {
    var vals  = elem.split('=');
    var $elem = $formularioEquipo.find("[name='" + vals[0] + "']");
    var value = decodeURIComponent(vals[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    if ($elem.is(':radio,:checkbox')) {
        $elem.prop('checked', ($elem.val() === value));
    } else {
        $elem.val(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution is not working for my checkbox.  if ($elem.is(':radio,:checkbox')) is always returning false.
Any advice?
<input type="checkbox" name="employments" id="employmentId4" value="4" data-text="Travel" checked="checked" class="hidden">